# Visual Studio can't launch app in IOS simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Visual Studio 15.6.4 running in a Windows 10 Parallels VM.

I create a new Cross platform Xamarin Forms Standard app

My Mac is paired (connected) successfully

I choose a simulator Iphone 8 iOS 11.2 for example

When I run the app

========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
Build started.
Project "App4.iOS.csproj" (GetAppBundleDir target(s)):
Done building project "App4.iOS.csproj".
Build succeeded.

the app does not get launched and it just stops without doing anything.

Please HELP

Comment: I fixed this by installing VS Enterprise.

Comment: I don't recommend the VS Professional 15.6.4 version. it is not stable and besides some templates are missing

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue several times. In my case there were some Xcode updates automatically installed on the Mac. Those updates either required to accept changed license agreements or to install additional components.

The solution in either case was to start Xcode on my Mac and follow the instructions on the screen.

I wrote a German blog post about that issue a while ago. You can find the [automatically translated version here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fandrekraemer.de%2Fblog%2Fxamarin-ios-simulator-stuerzt-mit-fehler-a-fatal-error-occured-when-trying-to-start-the-server-ab%2F&edit-text=)